# How to change grub timeout without entering into Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, grub4dos

My grub_timeout is 1 second and grub_default is win-10, now i cant boot into Ubuntu 18.1. The grub is directly taking lap to win-10 and grub doesn't respond to any input. **How to change the grub_timeout in this condition ?**

Comment: It does not respond even to ESC key?

Comment: You could boot with a live USB and change it.